# Saving values of a table output from stored procedure in a list

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have following code that is getting a table of values from a stored procedure. My goal is to save the table I recieve from the stored procedure into some list or IEnumerable to process it later in code.

Stored procedure returns two rows: id and Name. The code is working fine except when I use it to write values in a foreach loop to test, it only lists the column names not values.

```
 string cs =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ToString();
            string procName= "testing2";
            SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(cs);
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(procName, conn);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Rows";
                foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    c.ColumnMapping=MappingType.Attribute;
                    Console.WriteLine(c.ColumnName.ToArray());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("Error" + e);
            }
            finally
            {

                conn.Close();

            }
```

I think I am making mistake in the following two lines of code which is just writing the column names instead of values too:

```
c.ColumnMapping=MappingType.Attribute;
Console.WriteLine(c.ColumnName.ToArray());
```

Any suggestions how to correct it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over to the Rows Collection is you want to print the row values and for each row over the ItemArray that contains the single column values-

```
foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   for(int x = 0; x < r.ItemArray.Length; x++)
       Console.WriteLine(r.ItemArray[x].ToString());
   Console.WriteLine();    
}
```

Of course this is just an example. More robust code is needed to handle situations like null values.

Comment: This works fine gives me the rows. Thanks. However how can I save this in a list with column name to use it in doing calculations?

Comment: DataRow IS a list.  What more are you looking for??

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Look for a good and simple ORM. I use [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and it is a real lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

```
Console.WriteLine(c.ColumnName.ToArray() + ": " + c.ToNullSafeString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have sub processing calculation so just pass to that sub value of "DataSet ds" and in the sub treat it as a dataset to get any of the values you need.